# how write this in verbatim latex

Tags: latex, verbatim

i have a little question about the verbatim environment in latex.....
my problem is how can i write "\end{verbatim}" inside of a verbatim environment, it supposed that everything inside a verbatim is written just like it looks but this is the string to end the environment, so how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might be impossible in a `verbatim` environment -- at least, that's what Lamport says in the LaTeX book (first paragraph on pg. 64). However, you can do it with the `\verb` command: `\verb+\end{verbatim}+` works just fine (and in fact, you can use **any** character instead of `+` as long as you make them match).

That said, the `listings` package is smart enough to have an escape character. For example,

```
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=+]
+\verb!\end{lstlisting}!+
\end{lstlisting}
```

does exactly what you're looking for. (Again, pick a different character than `+` if you're already using that for something else.)

Comment: thanks, that works. Mmm I need a little more help, in a listing environment do you know how can i do the same? (write \end{lstlisting})I first ask for verbatim, because both environments write the text inside like they are written....the first solution that comes to my mind is just simply split the text in two parts so in the middle write \end{lstlisting} inside a \verb

Comment: Oh, `lstlisting` is smart enough to have an escape character for that -- updating answer now.

Answer (score 5):

```
 \\end{verbatim}
```

Should do it by making the initial `\` into a literal backslash.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/) package instead of the default `verbatim` package.

Comment: can you give and example?.....i read the documentation but i can't see the answer

Comment: Did you go to the link, download the `fancyvrb` package and use the `Verbatim` environment (capital `V`?)  If so, what did you see?

Answer (score 1):

Craig's answer is good.  Alternatively, `\expandafter\string\csname end{verbatim}\endcsname`.

These solutions won't linebreak nicely: fixing this is fiddly.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simpler solution. Write a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), in Emacs it's C-x 8 SPC (Windows, though I haven't tried it is `Alt+0160 (on numeric keypad)`). So, you can do this:

```
\begin{verbatim}
\_end{verbatim}
\end{verbatim}
```

where the first `\end{verbatim}` has this "_", the non-breaking character.

Comment: it adds a ugly space where it should not

Comment: no, it doesn't. It will add that character in the source, but it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my method, thanks @S.Lott for his advice.

If you want to write `\end{verbatim}` in the verbatim environment, you have to using another 'verbatim' layer to nest your code (this is where `fancyvr` package comes to play). Here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}           
\begin{document}
            
Some text here
    
\begin{Verbatim} % note 'uppercase V' in verbatim
                
\begin{verbatim}
Code example    
\end{verbatim}      
                
\end{Verbatim}
            
\end{document}
```